# Coffeescript and Ecmascript 6 get and set keywords

Tags: coffeescript, ecmascript-6

I'm running into an issue with coffeescript where I would like to be able to use the ecmascript get and set keywords, however the syntax doesn't make sense in coffeescript.

Here's an example of the original javascript

```
// A Tutorial class that takes a document in its constructor
Tutorial = function (id, name, capacity, owner) {
    this._id = id;
    this._name = name;
    this._capacity = capacity;
    this._owner = owner;
};

Tutorial.prototype = {
    get id() {
        // readonly
        return this._id;
    },
    get owner() {
        // readonly
        return this._owner;
    },
    get name() {
        return this._name;
    },
    set name(value) {
        this._name = value;
    },
    get capacity() {
        return this._capacity;
    },
    set capacity(value) {
        this._capacity = value;
    }
};
```

And here's an example of my best guess of what that might translate into:

```
class Question
  constructor: (id, @name, @capacity, @owner) ->
    @_id = id


Question::get id() ->
  return @_id
```

however that of course doesn't actually compile to anything useful.

I've seen a few examples of work arounds, but I guess the real question is whether there is any support for this at all in Coffescript directly?

Comment: To be fair, you shouldn't be using getters and setters at all here except for the `id`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think Coffeescript does support getter/setter declaration in object literals at all. It's been discussed multiple times, see issues [64](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffeescript/issues/64), [451](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffeescript/issues/451), [322](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffeescript/issues/322), [2878](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffeescript/issues/2878):

> In summary: we explicitly ignore the existence of setters/getters because we consider them a bad part of JS

The best workaround you can get is

```
Object.defineProperty Question::, "id",
  get: -> @_id
  enumerable: true
  configurable: true
```

Comment: Perfect example code, that's the main reason I would be using this.  Thx!